# Encountering an error during the configuration of Airflow on an Amazon EKS cluster with an RDS PostgreSQL database

Tags: airflow, amazon-eks

While setting up the Airflow application with helm chart, configured to use PostgreSQL RDS for metadata storage in a shared VPC with an EKS cluster, and ensuring communication between worker nodes and RDS is established, I've encountered an issue during the initialization container "airflow-migrations init." The error logs indicate an attempt to connect to "airflow-cluster-pgbouncer.airflow-cluster.svc.cluster.local" (192.168.115.94) instead of the expected RDS cluster. Notably, the same application operates successfully when configured with an embedded PostgreSQL database.

For more details please refer to this link:
https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/issues/809

Link to the airflow helm chart I used:
https://github.com/airflow-helm/charts/tree/main/charts/airflow

I have searched exhaustively for potential error sources but have been unsuccessful in finding a resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I do not 100% understand the issue, but I read it as you can connect to the original RDS DNS but not when it's using the `airflow-cluster-pgbouncer.airflow-cluster.svc.cluster.local` DNS from your Kubernetes cluster.

If that's the right understanding, I will try out if I was you create an external name with `airflow-cluster-pgbouncer` inside your `airflow-cluster` namespace where you defined your DNS to your RDS Cluster, the manifest can look like this

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: airflow-cluster-pgbouncer
  namespace: airflow-cluster
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: my.rds.database.example.com
```

Comment: Sorry for missing additional context (I have edited my comment now)
I was trying to deploy it with airflow helm chart. Do you know any work around for this issue?